# In ListView item, RelativeLayout child not expanding to fill free space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

inside **ListView item**  what I'm trying to do is to place an ImageView over a TextView while the TextView must fill it's parent, here's what i did:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFF00" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#550000FF" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

notes:

- tried to add {android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"} to TextView - nothing changed
- tried to use "fill_parent" instead of "match_parent" - nothing changed
- tried to add "android:singleLine="false"" - nothing changed
- ImageView height must be fixed, but i can't do then for TextView.
- there is no problem when the TextView contains enough text to make it taller than image

[here is a screenshot:](http://s14.postimg.org/tsypeaiox/Capture1.png)
notice that the TextView is acting like it's given "wrap_content" while it should be filling all the white space.

so what am I missing here?

thanks!

Comment: Do you want `android:gravity="center"` maybe?

Comment: the problem is when the height of TextView is Less than the height of ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Set the `TextView` height same as `ImageView`, since your using `Relative Layout` for the `ListView` item layout, the item height will be the maximum height of its inner child.

Change the `Textview` as

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />
```

If , the `ImageView` height is not fixed, then you can set the `TextView` height from your adapter `getView` method

```
  textview.setHeight(parent.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Also , setting `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for a `ListView` item `parent Layout` doesn't make any sense, change it to `wrap_content`

Comment: thanks for responding, can't fix textView height, maybe i have to do it programmatically, but how to predict textView height in getView method while setting text to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change parent layout height to `wrap_content` it will solve your issue

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#550000FF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

OR 
You can set `minHeight=100` to `TextView`. This will take minimum height 100dp same as `ImageView` and increase its height after minimum height.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFF00" />
```